# I study/I am studying

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

When speaking about studying is it proper to say in simple present like

- I study science in the university. or in simple present continuous as
- I am studying science in the university.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. We use the **present simple** for something that always, regularly or never happens.
2. We use the **present continuous** for something that is happening now.
3. We use the **present simple** for a fact that is always true.

   ---

> *I study sience in the university*.

This is something that happens regularly.

> *I am studying science in the University*.

This is something happening at this very moment. Normally continuous tenses have words like *at the moment, (right) now,* etc.

Comment: As you said I have to answer in the continuous form if I am in the science class at the moment. If someone ask me ."What are you studying in the university?.